# Good Plugin for Freeze column and fixed header in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for some good plugin for Freeze column and fixed header in Table

I am currently using GridViewScroll
http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

It doesn't support Spanning of rows ans columns.
I would like to have one which supports that.

Please make some good suggestions.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please, explain in detail. what do you mean by "Spanning of rows ans columns"?

Comment: I would like to have colspans and rowspans in the table. If i have spans in my table the above said GridViewScroll plugin does not produces required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can try this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rKjk3/15/).

It is not a plugin and ***not written by me***..I used it so may be it will be helpful to you.. You can edit the code to get desired results..

Basic functionality can be controlled through this:

```
$('#cTable').cTable({
        width: 800,
        height: 150, 
        fCols: 1,  //Number of columns to be fixed
        fRows: 1   // Number of rows to fixed
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I will try that and get back to u.